# Live Preview in different languages on different top level domains

Tags: localization, live-preview, multi-domain

Our website offers three different languages. Each language has it own top level domain (example: domain.de, domain.it, domain.fr). Everything works like it should, except the Live Preview function. We have already tryed the things described here: https://craftcms.com/support/cross-domain-live-preview and a few other tweeks we found in stackoverflow. Every solution we found, only works with subdomains.

As i understand, it's not possible because the browser does not allow cookies accross domains (Cross-Domain Policy).

Does anyone have experience with handling various languages and top level domains in Craft CMS? How can we handle this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current implementation of Live Preview in Craft, using Live Preview across different top-level domains isn't possible due to the cross-domain policy (as you found out) along with a few others.

We've got a few ideas on how we might address this in the future, but it will definitely be after Craft 3 comes out.