# Live preview not working for CORS

Tags: live-preview

For production site, the backend url is like - 'www.abc-prod.com'
While the actual live site url is - 'www.xyz.com'

When opening live preview for an entry, page never loads. Instead '301 Moved Permanently' is the status of response.

[image: Response Headers]

I have enabled CORS by adding following headers in response-

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.abc-prod.com
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Still getting blank page for live review. What exactly I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live Preview across different root domains is currently not possible in Craft. See here for more info: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14966/57

You can use it across different subdomains that share the same root domain, though: https://craftcms.com/support/cross-domain-live-preview